# CATransition animation zoom change image (UIImageView)

Tags: uiimageview, transition, cabasicanimation, catransform3d, catransition

I try to achieve zooming animation image change on UIImageView.

So far I created a transition of type `moveIn` and subtype `fromLeft`:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[transition setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[transition setDuration:1.5];

[[imageView layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

But I want a zooming effect. I successfully created it by using CABasicAnimation:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transition.scale"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]];
[animation setDuration:1.5];

[[imageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

My problem is that, using the second approach, the image changes (old image is gone) and then the animation comes in.

So it's an animation and not transition (as the names imply).

How can I create a transition with zoom effect?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: I don't remember anymore, sorry. I might have dropped the project...

Comment: That's alright, I was able to achieve my desired transition following [this guide](http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/).

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for that link, I think I'll get some fancy stuff done with it!

Answer (score 0):

Can use this to scale.

setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale